# Reading View Function with ethers.js returns error

Tags: ethers.js, view

I have the following code to read a function for a contract deployed on mainnet.

```
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  const response = await fetch('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0x67Dc577DEED1c30B0e611A66316741A6A7d57DBE&apikey=************');
  const data = await response.json();

  // print the JSON response 
  let abi = data.result;
  console.log(abi);
  
  // Connect to the network
  let provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('mainnet');
  // creating a new Provider, and passing in our node URL

  
  // The address from the above deployment example
  let contractAddress = "0x67Dc577DEED1c30B0e611A66316741A6A7d57DBE";
  
  // We connect to the Contract using a Provider, so we will only
  // have read-only access to the Contract
  let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
  //await contract.connect;
  console.log(contract.address);

  let ids = await contract.getMintedIds();
  await ids.wait();
  console.log(ids.toString());
```

It all works until the last 3 lines where I try to call the function. Then I get this error.
`TypeError: Not a string or buffer`
I know the function works, it returns the expected `uint16[]` when I view it on etherscan.
Any ideas about what I am missing?

Comment: Can you console.log(ids) and show the result?

Comment: No the code fails at:  let ids = await contract.getMintedIds();

Comment: What does `getMintedIds` do? I'd check that the address is the correct one, and do the same with the abi.

Comment: r u using webpack